# problem with quotes on new post

Tags: mysql, escaping

i have a little form to post:

```
$post_content = '"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."';

$post = array( 'post_author' => 1,
               'post_title' => 'title',
               'post_content' => $post_content,
               'post_category' => $categories,
               'post_type' => 'post'
             );
```

but, once my post is published shows :

```
&;Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit…&;
```

please note the `&;`

I've tried to escape before like this:

```
\"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...\"
```

but still the same.
 Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$post_content = '&quot;Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...&quot;';
```

Try encoding special characters. See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp & http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php